# Linking 'Backlog Items' to more than one level in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have created a project that has 3 levels; 'Milestones', 'Epics', 'Backlog Items'. Is it possible to create a new Work Item Type e.g. 'Work Lists', that will allow me the option to link 'Backlog Items' to either 'Epics' or the newly create 'Work Lists'?

For information, 'Work Lists' will not be linked to 'Milestones'.

Comment: What's type of the link? Backlog Item is the child item of Epics or Work Lists?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you should be using the **[Scrum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/scrum-process)** template.

As default in the process, you can link the '`Backlog Items`' to either '`Epics`' or '`Tasks`'.

So, you just need to create a new Work Item Type '`Work Lists`' as the same level as `Task`.

Refer to [Add or modify a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-wit) to add the new work item type.

However the easiest way is duplicating the `Task` type and modify it based on your requirements. See [TFS – Add or Duplicate a Work Item Type for details](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamicsaxdenismacchinetti/archive/2015/12/23/tfs-add-or-duplicate-a-work-item-type).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but you have misunderstood me.

I am using the Scrum template.  The 'Backlog Items' will be linked to 'Work Lists' or 'Epics'.  Is this possible?

To be clear, in this instance, 'Work Lists' are not 'Tasks', but 'Tasks' will of course be linked to 'Backlog items'.

Comment: @Rick So, what's the 'Work Lists'? you mentioned above it should be a new work item type. If it is , then yes, it's possible that the 'Backlog Items' can be linked to 'Work Lists' or 'Epics', just like the other WITs (eg, task, bug)

Comment: 'Work Lists' is to be a level of work within the project that won't have an end date, hence the reason why they won't be linked to 'Milestones'.  Since some 'Backlog Items' will be created for such work, they will be linked to 'Work Lists', not 'Epics'.

Comment: @Rick Still cannot get you very well, if you want to create a new work item type as task level, then 'Backlog Items' can be linked to that type you created as mentioned above, if you mean custom the process else, please clarify that, then we can give the suggestion accordingly.

Comment: Finally revisiting this issue after other priorities got in the way.

"Work Lists" is just a title, but essential on a similar level to 'Epics'.  This is because I want to choose to link a 'Backlog Item' to either an 'Epic' or 'Work Lists'.

Process is a follows:

Backlog Item > Epic> Milestone

or

Backlog Item > Work List